# Ubuntu 18.04 failing to install texlive

Tags: package-management, 18.04, latex

I have a freshly installed 18.04, and I have issues installing TeXlive.
In particular, the error is:

```
dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 installed tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The last lines of the log are:

```
root@Goku:/home/pecos# tail /tmp/fmtutil.PbGasdaf
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dviluatex -progname=dviluatex dviluatex.ini </dev/null' return status 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini </dev/null' return status 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: Disabled formats: 2
fmtutil [INFO]: Successfully rebuilt formats: 8
fmtutil [INFO]: Failed to build: 4 (luatex/luatex luatex/dvilualatex luatex/dviluatex luatex/lualatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 14
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 4
```

I can't figure out what the problem might be... any suggestion ?

Comment: What happens if you manually run the `luatex -ini   -jobname=dviluatex -progname=dviluatex dviluatex.ini </dev/null` command?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy tex-common` to the question.

Comment: @Norbert: tex-common:
  Installed: 6.09
  Candidate: 6.09
  Version table:
 *** 6.09 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: @steeldriver the command works if I call it from the terminal

Comment: It seems that asking to run "sudo apt install texlive" fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have installed LaTeX in my Ubuntu 18.04 (fresh installation) without any problems having `main`, `universe`, `restricted` and `multiverse` repositories enabled. Try this:

```
sudo apt install texlive texlive-full imagemagick
```

Comment: I spent much of the early morning hours trying to find a work-around to the Texlive2018 errors. This line works! Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it does _not_ work for my system, a KDE neon based on Ubuntu 18.04. THe process results in a "too many errors" which can be traced down finally as spin offs of the original issue with tex-common.

Comment: `Need to get 2884 MB of archives.`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same errors when trying to install `texlive-full` on a fresh KDE Neon installation (18.04 base).

For me, the problem was a missing locale. Apt printed warning messages about it and it turns out that generating the missing locale for my system fixed the issue.
Check your locale configuration with the command:

```
$ locale
```

Then, check which locales are available on your system with the command:

```
$ locale -a
```

Identify the missing locale(s) (for example `en_US.UTF-8`), then generate them with the command (and expected output):

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Then resume the failed installations with:

```
$ sudo apt install -f
```

At the end, I got a message saying:

```
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (6 vs 13).
   Affected packages: context:amd64 tex-common:amd64
```

I decided to fix this by reinstalling them:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall context tex-common
```

Hope this helps!